# Convert image to textual form(compressed) and back from text to image in android

Tags: java, android, image

hello there i want to convert an image to compressed textual form and then i want to send it to the other android user in form of sms and then that textual form need to be converted to the Image, i tried with the base64 encoding but its of no use, because its output is very long.. so that it ll be tough to send that much of text in form of sms, so is there any other way to covert an image to text else any method to compress the text...? please help me and i am work on android emulator and really need your help. Thanks in advance 
Regards Hitesh,

Answer (score 0):

Base64 must be OK, because it converts 3 bytes of data to 4 characters of text. You can't decrease size of your data using textual representation. But you can try to compress data and then convert it to text. Maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 encodes the data in base 64, i.e., using 64 different characters. According to [the Wikipedia page on SMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS) an SMS can contain any 7-bit character (that is, you have 128 characters at your disposal!)

Here's the best way to do it:

1. Compress the image using a compression method of your preference. (jpg for instance)
2. Find out the sequence of bits that the jpg-data has.
3. Write this bits as 7-bit characters. (Take special care of padding the last 7 bits.)
4. Write this sequence of characters as an SMS.